# Synced code from windows 7 to windows 10. Now have errors with line endings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, github-for-windows

I was working on a project last night in windows 7, i finished so used github-visual studio extension to sync with my repository. Pulled it up on my windows 10 machine this morning and all of a sudden i am getting a message saying that the file endings are inconsistent, so i tried both leaving them and changing them. No matter what i am doing i am getting this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x75AD2CD2 in BreakoutDebug.exe: Microsoft C++ >exception: tle::CTLException at memory location 0x012FF5DC.

I have tried re-cloning the repository to see if that made any difference, but to no avail and also tried using the vs feature where it sorts out line ending inconsistencies for you

This is the line that is showing the error:

```
while (engine->IsRunning())
{
    engine->DrawScene();
        //All code to move sprites goes here

}
```

Comment: Concerning incosistent line-endings: This happens if you edit source code with unix line endings in VS in combination with copy paste. It's annoying but concerning C++ code IMHO harmless. VS offers an option to repair this. Notepad++ can visualize control characters and provides a command to change line endings. Concerning your exception, I would wonder whether line-endings are the reason. The C++ compiler doesn't care about even mixed line-endings. Other tools might, especially when borrowed from Unix world. (I once had issues with `awk` which was part of cygwin.)

Comment: Another stupid idea: Did you try a complete rebuild on your Windows 10 box? I didn't have this issue for a long time anymore but in the past sometimes time-stamps of pulled files were somehow scrambled for whatever reason. So, VS linked outdated object files without re-compiling them as necessary. This is good for any strange and hard to explain effect.

Comment: I thought it was inconsistent line endings purely because they came up at the same time, could very well be a coincidence. I have not as of yet as i was hoping that i would find an easier solution on here but it's my next shot, we'll see, going to go and start commenting out code to see if its anything else in the solution then try to rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was that the framework i was using was vs2015 version and relied on old dependancies, updatedto 2017 version of framework and it works fine